# Uninstall with KDE menu

Tags: uninstall, kde, context-menu

I'm running Kubuntu 12.04.

After I installed Xfce 4 on my system with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.10
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Now I am able to right click mouse on KDE menu to get additional option UNINSTALL 
I can delete software straight from desktop - from KDE MENU

How can I get this without installing XFCE?

Comment: Same kind of from the Kubuntu Forums: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?58267-KDE-4-8-2-Uninstall-entry-on-right-clic-in-KickOff

Answer (score 1):

Thanks user26687!

Yes after I installed sessioninstaller I can again uninstall software from KDE menu :D
[image]